# Entity Framework Core DB first, How to add an entity association in different C# core projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffold

I want to add the Entity folder in the Domain project, DBContext in the Persistence project, both are dll projects, but this script doesn't do it.

How can I do that?

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection Name=connectionString
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -ContextDir DBContext -OutputDir path -Namespace  Domain -ContextNamespace  Persistence -force

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. You can only specify one target project, where both entites and DbContext are scaffolded. See the documentation for [Scaffold-DbContext command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext).

If I were you I would set the target project, to your Domain project and then moved the DbContext class to your Persistence project. It's the easiest way.

To specify target project, use the `-Project` [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell#common-parameters).